# how to find the natural order of a element in XML?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have to find the natural order of element in the xml .i am not sure where to start ?

here is the requirement :

```
   <test>
    <test1>
        <figure id ="1"/> 
    </test1>
    <test1>
        <figure id ="2"/> 
        <test1>
            <figure id ="3"/> 
        </test1>
        <test1>
            <figure id ="4"/> 
        </test1>
    </test1>

    <test1>
        <figure id ="5"/> 
    </test1>

    <test1>
        <figure id ="6"/> 

        <test1>
            <figure id ="7"/> 
        </test1>

        <test1>
            <figure id ="8"/> 
            <test1>
                <figure id ="9"/> 

                <test1>
                    <figure id ="10"/> 
                    <test1>
                        <figure id ="11"/> 


                    </test1>

                </test1>
            </test1>

        </test1>

    </test1>
</test>
```

I have to find the correct order of all the figure element 
In the above sample code figure there are 11 figure element . and i have to get the order of each figure element ,

Suppose for the moment i am at element `<figure id ="10"/>`

then i have to count all the figure element before that (total 9)

I am processing the xml in java using the dom .
and at run time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the root element and call [`root.getElementsByTagName("figure")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName(java.lang.String)) it should return a `NodeList` with the elements in the order in which they appear in the document. If convenient, you could then iterate through the `NodeList` and build a map from id value to `<figure>` element, or build an array of `<figure>` elements, or build any other convenient data structure depending on your processing requirements.